# Update close question reason?

Tags: discussion, support, suggestion

I suggest we update the close question reason for health or nutrition as follows (new text in bold) to emphasize that health factors are included as off topic (excuse the extra space that is an artifact of markdown limitations):

> Questions on nutrition **, health** or requests for medical advice are
>   off-topic here; you should contact a qualified medical professional
>   instead.

If we are up against a character count limit, I suggest:

> Questions on nutrition, health or requests for medical advice are
>   off-topic here; instead contact a qualified medical professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is reasonable. But we [can't actually edit them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186336/how-do-i-edit-custom-close-reasons), because it'd retroactively change what's stamped on closed questions.

We can deactivate this one and add a replacement one, though. Since it's deliberately this much trouble to do, we should make sure we have the wording *exactly* how we want it.

Comment: Accepting this one just so the community process stops bringing it to the top.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 400 characters. If we're trying to keep it ultra short and sweet:

> Requests for health, diet, nutrition, or medical advice are off-topic here and should be referred to a qualified medical professional instead.

That's less than half of the limit. A more informative version would be:

> Questions about health, diet, or nutrition (except for those following the guidelines of [food-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-safety) or [nutrition](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition)<sup>*</sup> tags) are off-topic, especially when of a non-culinary nature or when phrased as requests for medical advice. Please consult a qualified medical professional such as a dietitian.

...which is still well under the limit.

<sub>* We should create a tag wiki for this explaining [what types of nutrition questions are allowed](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1771/41)</sub>

Comment: P.S. It probably doesn't help that we *have* a "nutrition" tag, even if we regulars know that it has a technically narrower meaning. Maybe we should change it to "nutritional-content"?

Comment: I agree; what is an on-topic nutrition question?  Even nutritional-content seems borderline to me.  Also, I think we should *not* mention phrasing--its the content that is significant.